# SQL Server CHARINDEX function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for some function that replace all Rows in column with for loop or different way. The function need to give substring from specific character by revers (third backslash from end)

Before : `'חוזה - דף ראשון#Y:\Access\Shiduhim\Agreem1\999999.Bmp'`

Need to be after method : `'Shiduhim\Agreem1\999999.Bmp'`

Comment: I don't really follow what you're asmking here. What have you tried so far, and why isn't it working? That will likely help us.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the second `'\'` by passing the the first occurrence (+1) to the `start_location` parameter of `CHARINDEX()` function as

```
SELECT S, RIGHT(S, LEN(S) - IX)
-- Or you can use REPLACE(S, LEFT(S, IX), '')
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (N'חוזה - דף ראשון#Y:\Access\Shiduhim\Agreem1\999999.Bmp' )
) T(S) CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
  (CHARINDEX('\', S, CHARINDEX('\', S)+1))
) TT(IX)
```

<kbd>[`Online Demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=54eafa58e89eb076944ed9f028c60b60)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) (need to know about [`maxrecursion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-maxrecursion-to-cancel-a-statement)):

```
declare @t table(
  path nvarchar(260)
);

insert into @t(path) values
  (N'חוזה - דף ראשון#Y:\Access\Shiduhim\Agreem1\999999.Bmp'),
  ('C:\abc\defg\hi.png'),
  ('17042.jpg'),
  ('D:\foo\bar.tiff');

declare @n int = 3;

with
  r as (
    select r, 0 as p, 0 as n, iif(charindex('\', r) > 0, 1, 0) as x
    from @t
    cross apply (select reverse(path)) as a(r)
    union all
    select r, a.p, n + 1, iif(n < @n - 1 and charindex('\', r, a.p + 1) > 0, 1, 0)
    from r
    cross apply (select charindex('\', r, p + 1)) as a(p)
    where x = 1
  )
select
  reverse(iif(n < @n, r, left(r, p - 1))) as path
from r
where x = 0;
```

**Output:**

```
+-----------------------------+
|            path             |
+-----------------------------+
| 17042.jpg                   |
| D:\foo\bar.tiff             |
| abc\defg\hi.png             |
| Shiduhim\Agreem1\999999.Bmp |
+-----------------------------+
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/IVSHH37278).